# Learning Ember.js- How Would I do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js

To learn Ember.js I started writing a small [bookmark application](https://home.mythli.net/web/ember/bookmarker/).
Bookmarks with the selected label should be displayed in the bottom box.

**Template:**

```
...
{{#each itemController="label"}}
  <li>
    <a href="#" {{bind-attr class=":label active:label-primary:label-default"}} {{action 'findLinks'}}>{{name}}</a>
  </li>
{{/each}}
...
{{#each links}}
  <li>{{name}}</li>
{{/each}}
...
```

**App.LabelController:**

```
...
App.LabelController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ["list"],
    active: false,

    actions: {
        findLinks: function() {
            var listController = this.get('controllers.list');

            this.toggleProperty('active');
            listController.set('model', this.get('store').find('link'));
        }
    }
});
...
```

**Label Data:**

```
App.Label = DS.Model.extend({
    links: DS.hasMany('link'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    color: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Label.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Develop',
        color: 'blue'
    },
    ...
];
```

**Link Data:**

```
App.Link = DS.Model.extend({
    labels: DS.hasMany('label'),
    name: DS.attr(),
    url: DS.attr()
});

App.Link.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Google',
        url: 'http://google.com',
        labels: [1]
    },
    ...
];
```

The issue I have now is that setting the model in LabelController doesn't update the list of links. I also doubt that this is the right approuch.

How would you do such a thing in Ember?

Edit:
http://jsbin.com/Ovuw/81/edit

Comment: Can you set a JsFiddle with the code? Preconfigured starting points http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ember.js/info

Comment: I set up a JsFiddle. Meanwhile you can also see the running application here: https://home.mythli.net/web/ember/bookmarker/

Comment: Yeah I saw it, but with all the code in one site is better for answer your question...

Comment: I added a JS Bin. I was struggling with the dependency on the Ember.js data library as I couldn't find a hosted copy.

Comment: Can use this http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.0.0-beta.3/ember-data.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? http://jsbin.com/Ovuw/83/edit I commented the code, if you have questions be free to comment

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your insightful answer.